# How can I add Google Drive to "This PC" in the Windows Explorer sidebar?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, google-drive

The title says it all really. I have Google Drive already installed of course.

Comment: I have added my google drive under the favourites section. Will that be ok for you?

Comment: nah, but thanks. I have that already but in windows 8.1 the sidebar list is so long compared to previous versions of windows that it is better for me in "This PC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 3rd Party application [This PC Tweaker from Winaero](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213) to achieve this.

1. Run the portable application (no installation necessary)
2. Choose "Add Custom Folder"
3. Navigate to your Google Drive folder and select it from within the file browser

And that should be it. I haven't used this personally so I apologise for any mistake and please correct me if you try this out.

Detailed instructions can be found at [their blog post](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-folders-in-this-pc-in-windows-8-1-or-remove-the-defaults/)

Comment: great! worked perfectly. Cool site, will have to investigate other things on offer there when I have some time